# checking for duplicate product_name PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am trying to check if the *product_name* is already existing in the database and if it is to display error!

```
$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $product_name = sanitize($product_name);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = '$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $match = mysql_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    if (($match > 0)===true) {
         $errors[]='Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system!';
         break 1;
    }
```

Thanks indeed

Comment: is $product_name correct after the mysql_real_escape_string and your sanitize function?

Comment: What happens when you run the code above? Does php report any errors? Is this code missing real duplicates? Is this code reporting duplicates where none exist? What we can see looks like it should work, though `($match > 0)===true` is pretty strange and we can't see what loop you're `break`ing out of.

Comment: How about simply: `if ($match) {`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this should also work just edit this to

```
  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = '".$product_name."'";
```

Also i think limit 1 is not need as you are just checking if it is greater then 0 then error.
Also change this

```
if (($match > 0)===true) {
```

to

```
if ($match > 0) {
     echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system!';
}
else
{
  //Code for insertion or whatever you want to do if its not an error
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this.

```
if ($match > 0) {
```

instead ,

```
if (($match > 0)===true) {
```

Cheers!

PS: Don't use mysql_query(), it's obsolete. Use mysqli_query() instead. So for mysql_num_rows(). Refer to PHP documentation : - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Hey 
yes i tried with 

`if ($match > 0) {`

as well but still does not work :\
any others suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: What does $match returns ? Have you `var_dump($match);` to see what it returns? Your LIMIT 1 is doesn't not needed as you are just trying to see records exists or not.